# yii2 CSRF not working properly

Tags: csrf, yii2-advanced-app, code-security

I copied create form code from view source when user use to logged in and then I created html file from copied code then I logged out and then logged in again. when i submited html file then system accept it witout any csrf checking. not sure where issue is. csrf is enabled also _csrf code also avaiable in view source too

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="ttPy-NP-8FUCQxKczEWgkl66JQfb3JfJHwUOSsi9wjTxkp_LgKqxFFYBQu2iL8T2LIxpQ7Xuzo0ucEYfjPSUBg==">
```

Comment: Can you share your form code? Are you using get or post?

Comment: @VipinMohan its post base and its also sending _csrf as hidden field

Answer (score 0):

It resolved reason being it happend becuase csrf validation via cookie so it not clear cookie properly when user logged out. so easy solution for this is do changes in main.php

```
'request' => [
        'enableCsrfCookie' => false,
    ],
```